# Join a table to get the output by making one column as two columns (or simply split one column into 2 columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join a table to get the output by making one column as two columns (or simply split one column into 2 columns)

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT;

KEY| PRODUCT |CATEGORY
1  | trip    |city
2  | trip    |ocean
```

Into

```
KEY| PRODUCT |CATEGORY1 |CATEGORY2
1  | trip    |city      |ocean
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation . . . but this only works for two categories:

```
select min(key), product,
       min(category), nullif(max(category), min(category))
from t
group by product;
```

More commonly when listing multiple values for a product (such as categories), you would put the results in a JSON array or a string:

```
select min(key), product,
       string(category, ',') within group (order by category) as categories
from t
group by product;
```